# for loop causing a deadlock in c# and stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, deadlock, sql-server-2019

I've spent long time try to solve this deadlock. The daedlock is in the `_dbcontext.DeleteTags(tag);`

The `AddTags` and `DeleteTags` goes to the same graphtable (this is the reason that I can't use EF to delete/insert, as it is not supported yet) However, the deadlock is happening in the `DeleteTags` maybe because of the for-loop. Would you please advise on how to sort this?

```
public async Task UpdateScenario()

try
{
    await _businessCore.TransactionManager.Begin();

    _dbcontext.MyData.Update(scenario);

    foreach (var tag in newtags)
    {
        tag.LabelGroupId = labelGroup.LabelGroupId;
        tag.LabelId = (await _dbcontext.AddTags(tag)).LabelId;
        tag.Attributes.ToList().ForEach(z => z.LabelId = lbl.LabelId);
    }

    foreach (var tag in deletedTags)
    {
        await _dbcontext.DeleteTags(tag);
    }

    await Validation.SaveChangesWithValidation(_dbcontext);
    await _businessCore.TransactionManager.Commit();
}
catch
{
   await _businessCore.TransactionManager.Rollback();
   throw;
}
```

`DeleteTag` function

```
public async Task DeleteTag(Tags tag)
{
    await this.Labels.FromSqlInterpolated($"exec uspDeleteTag {tag.LabelId}").ToListAsync();
}
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspDeleteTags] 
    (@LabelId INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tgphLabel 
    OUTPUT DELETED.LabelId, DELETED.LabelTypeId, DELETED.LabelGroupId
    WHERE LabelId = @LabelId;
END
```

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.. thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Do you have multiple indexes on tgphLabel? you can probably use tablock or perhaps instead of doing a looped delete, create a procedure that can delete multiple tags at once

Comment: @siggemannen no.. there is no primary key for it as well. the table is GRAPH_UNIQUE_INDEX

Comment: @siggemannen do i need to add trans begin and commit inside the sp as well?

Comment: don't think it's needed, if you just have one statement

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you have a transaction surrounding everything, but when you call the stored procedure, this is not part of the transaction.  I would suggest writing a single SP that does both all the insertions and all deletions within a transaction inside the SP itself.

Comment: Off topic here - the real SQL specialists are on dba.stackexchange.com which is where this should be redirected. Given that a deadlock is a DB level operation, you should not think C# but provide full SQL level trace information. There IS a profilder, you know, for sql server.

Comment: Is newTags also filled from the tgphLabel and the transaction for that uncommited? You need concurrent transactions to get into a deadlock and i can't see another one in the shown code.

Comment: There's something wrong with the code snippet, `deletedTags` is never declared. Can you post a full, compiling example?

Comment: This will not fix the deadlock (or it probably won't) - but if you don't have an index on `LabelId` in the table `tgphLabel`, it means every DELETE command will have to read the entire table to identify all the relevant rows matching LabelID. With an index on LabelId, at least the number of reads will be minimised (and it will speed up this process) unless the table is really small.

Comment: @seanb that table is a graph table and it is really huge